# How do capture data from complexity xml file to sql or nosql in python or Solr?

Tags: python, sql, xml, nosql

Capture value from xml file then turn it into sql. The final purpose is able to search and display desired related value and convert it into pdf file.

I m using python element tree to capture value from xml file and convert into pandas dataframe. Then using pyodbc or sqlite to table. However, it only ok for 1 xml file, if have bulk of xml file, what method should i use for complete this task?

Or anybody know how do modify xml file schema of SOLR?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: the problem is i need to capture value from xml file then convert to sql or nosql. I wonder is it any solution or method can capture value from xml file and convert to sql or nosql  directly. Currently, I using indirect method (element tree trace the xml and use panda convert is as dataframe). But it has a lot of hardcoding.

Comment: Still unclear, I'm afraid. Please show us code.